# htaccess how to get params after second question mark in url?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have already htaccess rewrited url like this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !-f
RewriteCond $1 !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

e.g. url: http://www.smth.com/en/page/subpage/ in PHP script i can get these params simply calling $_GET['page'].

But if my url looks like:
http://www.smth.com/en/page/subpage/?data=one&result=two

How can I get these **data=one&result=two** params in PHP?

Comment: You need to add QSA to the RewriteRule `[L,QSA]`.
The QSA means "Query String Append"

Comment: Thank You, It worked like charm. I was using [L,QSA] for a while but never really cared about what it meant.